# Resource file location in runnable jar

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project, that has resources files under dir `src/main/resources`. I noticed that in Eclipse, when I run the project, the source files are copied to `target/classes` without the resources directory, just the files under resources dir.
[image]

But after I exported the project to a runnable jar by using `Right clieck on the project -> Jar -> Runnable Jar` , these resource files are under resource directory:

[image]

As you see, the resource files are in diffrenent locations in two cases.

and below code works well in Eclipse, but not worked in runnable jars

`getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("database.properties")`

How to solve this problem? I want the above code can work in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is two different build processes, and most projects will use a single build system. It is a lot of effort for not a lot of benefit. You can initiate `mvn package` from eclipse as well. I would recommend maven since it is a standard. If you must do it, here are some ideas

- In your startup process, test to see if `/resources` exists and prefix all paths with it
- If its a single file, you can test and fall back on the second path
- Tweak your pom.xml to put your resource folder at /resource

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple - do NOT trust Eclipse or any IDE for similar cases. Matters only separate build that will be running on the separate environment. The same also applies to the testing using embedded in IDE application or web servers - it's a source of a huge number of potential issues